# Lambda and S3 Permission denied when want to create file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

My python code takes information from others web sites and creates json file. On local computer it works good but when I try to run code in Lambda I have error.
I have used different methods to creation file:

```
file = open('test.json', 'w')
```

and

```
oldumask = os.umask(0)
fdesc = os.open('test.json', os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT, 0o600)
file = os.fdopen(fdesc, "w")
```

Error message:

```
{
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/awsewt1.py",
      24,
      "handler",
      "fdesc = os.open('test.json', os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT, 0o600)"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "OSError",
  "errorMessage": "[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test.json'"
}
```

Code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import json
import urllib
import boto3
import os, stat

access_key = 'hide'
secret_key = 'hide'

def loadJSONByURL(url,key):
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    content = response.read()
    data = json.loads(content)
    text = {key:data}
    return text

def handler(event, context):
    phattha = "hide"
    phuket = "hide"
    koSamui = "hide"
    oldumask = os.umask(0)
    fdesc = os.open('test.json', os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT, 0o600)
    file = os.fdopen(fdesc, "w")
    json.dump(loadJSONByURL(phattha,'phatthaya'), file)
    json.dump(loadJSONByURL(phuket,'phuket'), file)
    json.dump(loadJSONByURL(koSamui,'koSamui'), file)
    file.close()
    conn = S3Connection(access_key,secret_key)
    bucket = conn.get_bucket('ewtbucket')

    key1 = bucket.get_key('test.json')
    if key1:
        key1.delete()
    key = bucket.new_key('/test.json')
    key.set_contents_from_filename('test.json')
    key.set_acl('public-read')

s3 = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    handler(event,context)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your Lambda function will not have local file write permissions everywhere on the machine.  Try writing to the `/tmp` directory:

```
file = open('/tmp/test.json', 'w')
```

Comment: Thanks, you are genius! :)